# uhh why does my fluid acting up like this? it was working before, the fluid came from the circle but now it looks like this, check the photo

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

I was just following a fluid tutorial and i tried it with a simple donut, it was perfectly fine at first but i feel like the result is very bad so i took a nother try. When i try to bake the fluid again it comes up like what is shown on the picture

Answer (score 0):

Try baking it a third time, but move the circle up a bit first.